# Best way to integrate searching with pagination

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a web application build on cakephp 2.x.

I have integrated pagination on my data.

Now i want to implement searching on that data also, and pagination should work according to search result.

Now my question is:

1. Should i use a form to post my search string. If so, then which method should i use, GET or POST.
2. OR, should i use javascript window.location method, and append the search string to it. If we use this method then search string can append more than once to url.
3. Or any other best way to implement this.

**Can anybody give the best solution** for this as it is a common task for each application to have.

Comment: Why downvote for such a useful question. Reason Should also be given with down vote. This question deserves up-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement search in cakephp best way to implement is with form. You can use any method GET/POST but GET method is recommended as it'll allow user to bookmark his search result.

Given below is the tutorial to implement search with pagination.

http://mrphp.com.au/blog/search-forms-cakephp

Comment: thanks mohit for your valuable response. I have implemented your mentioned solution and it is working fine. but i could not understand use for **$paginator->options(array('url' => $this->passedArgs))**, because links are remembering search options without using this line also.